# Add a non escaped escape character to python bytearray

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

I have an API that is demanding that the quotation marks in my XML attributes are escaped, so <cmd_id="1"> will not work, it requires <cmd_id=\"1\">.

I have tried iterating through my string, for example:

```
b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?>\n<tx><cmd id="1">SetChLevel</cmd><name>C</name><value>30</value></tx>'
```

Each time that I encounter a " (ascii 34) I will replace it with an escape character (ascii 92) and another quote.  Infuriatingly this results in:

```
b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?>\n<tx><cmd id=\\"1\\">SetChLevel</cmd><name>C</name><value>30</value></tx>'
```

where the escapes have been escaped.  As a sanity check I replaced 92 with any other character and it works as expected.

```py
temp = b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?>\n<tx><cmd id="1">\
SetChLevel</cmd><name>C</name><value>30</value></tx>'

i = 0
j = 0
payload = bytearray(len(temp) + 4)

for char in temp:
    if char == 34:
        payload[i] = 92
        i += 1
        payload[i] = 34
        i += 1
        j += 1
    else:
        payload[i] = temp[j]
        i += 1
        j += 1

print(bytes(payload))
```

I would assume that character 92 would appear once but something is escaping the escape!

Comment: I did a test and it seems like bytes() is adding the escape.

Comment: Just to be clear, `bytes()` isn't adding anything, but what gets printed to the screen has added stuff, because the function printing it adds stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the result of a very common misunderstanding for programmers new to Python.

When printing a string (or bytes) to the console, Python escapes the escape character (`\`) to show a string that, when used in Python as a literal, would give you the exact same value.

So:

```
s = 'abc\\abc'
print(s)
```

Prints `abc\abc`, but on the interpreter you get:

```
>>> s = 'abc\\abc'
>>> print(s)
abc\abc
>>> s
'abc\\abc'
```

Note that this is correct. After all `print(s)` should show the string on the console as it is, while `s` on the interpreter is asking Python to show you the *representation* of s, which includes the quotes and the escape characters.

Compare:

```
>>> repr(s)
"'abc\\\\abc'"
```

`repr` here prints the representation of the representation of `s`.

For `bytes`, things are further complicated because the representation is printed when using `print`, since print prints a string and a `bytes` needs to be decoded first, i.e.:

```
>>> print(some_bytes.decode('utf-8'))  # or whatever the encoding is
```

In short: your code was doing what you wanted it to, it does not duplicate escape characters, you only thought it did because you were looking at the representation of the bytes, not the actual bytes content.

By the way, this also means that you don't have to be paranoid and go through the trouble of writing custom code to replace characters based on their ASCII values, you can simply:

```
>>> example = bytes('<some attr="value">test</some>', encoding='utf-8')
>>> result = example.replace(b'"', b"\\\"")
>>> print(result.decode('utf-8'))
<some attr=\"value\">test</some>
```

I won't pretend that `b"\\\""` is intuitive, perhaps `b'\\"'` is better - but both require that you understand the difference between the representation of a string, or its printed value.

So, finally:

```
>>> example = b'<some attr="value">test</some>'
>>> result = example.replace(b'"', b'\\"')
>>> print(result.decode('utf-8'))
<some attr=\"value\">test</some>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!  It seems to be a pattern that Python is one step ahead of the way I am thinking about the problem.  It has been implemented and works.  Of course, as is the nature of these things it turns out the problem with the API was that the XML Elementree was not placing a newline after the XML declaration.  I will never get back these hours but at least I learned more about Python strings.

Comment: It's often only after I code something in Python that I find there's already something doing the exact same thing, either in a library or an external package. Problem is, often you don't know what to ask for before you've tried you hand at doing it - learning by doing isn't a waste of your time, even if you end up not using your own code, just a bit hard to explain to the bosses and clients ;-)